# Getting hibernate information about entites at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am seeking a way to get information about my hibernate entity classes at runtime. In detail I would need information like

> Class ABC has the properties a, b and c  with c being a
>   list and association to class XYZ

for the class

```
public class ABC {
    private int a;
    private String b;

    @OneToMany
    Private List<XYZ> c;
}
```

All that is needed at runtime. I am sure Hibernate knows all that at runtime, but I am not aware how to get these information.

Comment: Thanks for your hints folks - thats all I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PersistentClass userMapping = cfg.getClassMapping(ABC.class);
```

cfg is an instance of Hibernate Configuration.

[PersistentClass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass.html) has all the info you need.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Hibernate as a JPA 2 provider, then you can use the JPA 2 metamodel([`javax.persistence.metamodel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/package-summary.html)).  This will give you information about your JPA entities from the JPA metadata:

```
entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(entityClass). getAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like reflection is what you are after, its not hibernate specific information you seem to be after. You just want information about what fields the class has and what types they are...

Comment: With reflection to you need to be aware that some ORM solutions use bytec ode manipulation to add fields in order to facilitate such things as change tracking and lazy loading.  You may find more that you are looking for with reflection alone.  This is one of the reasons the JPA 2 spec has introduced a metamodel:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564955/getting-hibernate-information-about-entites-at-runtime/5567136#5567136

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information using reflection.

```
Class abcClass= ABC.class;
Field[] fields = abcClass.getDeclaredFields();
```

Comment: Yes, but only partly. Especially information about generic types in associations are hidden due to type erasure.